# Bag Identification: Bag 5 Possible Alien kit

Tags: model-identification

We have an unidentified bag #5. It matches the color palette from [Space Mission 11022](https://brickset.com/sets/11022-1/Space-Mission) bag 5: Black, Magenta, Grey, Purple, Neon Yellow.

Distinct pieces include 4 silver grey ray guns, 4 silver grey chalets, 5 purple bionicles.

Comment: Please add a photo of your bag and its contents.

Comment: Hi Meagan and welcome to Bricks.SE! I took the liberty to edit your post to better fit the site's rules and customs, but I can't figure out what you meant by "chalet" - surely not the Alpine lodging. Similarly, there are hundreds of Bionicle pieces so that's not something one can use to identify your set. I can only second Alex's request for a photo, where the individual pieces are clearly visible (take care with focusing, lighting and resolution). Meanwhile, feel free to take the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn more about the site and how things are done here. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb here, but can it be that your bag is indeed THE #5 bag from [Space Mission 11022](https://brickset.com/sets/11022-1/Space-Mission)? It ticks off all boxes:

- Matches the color palette of bag #5 from [Space Mission 11022](https://brickset.com/sets/11022-1/Space-Mission) (obviously):
  [image: Inspiration image for Space Mission 11022 bag #5, containing mostly Black, Magenta, Grey, Purple, and Neon Yellow pieces]
- Has exactly four of [Minifigure, Weapon Space Ray Gun - Rounded Heat Diffusers](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=13608&idColor=95#T=C&C=95) in flat silver:

[image: Minifigure, Weapon Space Ray Gun - Rounded Heat Diffusers]

- Has four [Minifigure, Utensil Goblet](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2343&idColor=95#T=C&C=95) pieces in flat silver (the words "chalet" and "goblet" do sound quite similarly):

[image: Minifigure, Utensil Goblet]

- Has four plus one spare, so five purple [Barb / Claw / Horn / Tooth - Medium](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87747&idColor=89#T=C&C=89) pieces, which (in various colors) have indeed appeared in 24 Bionicle sets:

[image: Barb / Claw / Horn / Tooth - Medium]

Comment: This was our original thought as well. However, we completed all builds and were left with a significant amount. None of the items like the goblet were referenced. We wanted to make sure we didn't miss a build. It looks like these are for create your own. Appreciate your response.

Comment: @Meagan "_we completed all builds and were left with a significant amount_" 
That's entirely intentional - see this excerpt of the official product description: 
"Includes everything kids need to create 10 space-themed toys, _plus lots of LEGO® bricks for free-build_ space creations". Have fun with all the creative possibilities :)